# How to apply a dictionary to a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reading a TFRecord format dataset, consisting of an image and its label, i.e, my target variable. The label is represented by 5 ints ranging from 0 to 4. The function I use to read the dataset is the following:

```
def read_tfrecord(sample):
tfrecord_format = {
    "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    "target": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
}
sample = tf.io.parse_single_example(sample, tfrecord_format)
image = decode_image(example['image'])
label = tf.cast(example['target'], tf.int32)        
return image, tf.reshape(tf.one_hot([label], depth=5, axis=-1), [-1])
```

The code works, but I would like to make a change. I would like to change the *label* as follows: 0,1,2,3 to 0 and 4 to 1. I tried to apply a dictionary to *label* but I don't know how to handle tensors very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to change the tensor itself, you can use `tf.map_fn`. It will apply a function to each element. I'll use constant tensors here to demonstrate the idea.

```
fn = lambda x: tf.constant(1) if tf.equal(x,4) else tf.constant(0)
res = tf.map_fn(fn, tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4]))
```

When you print tensor `res`, it shows  of `<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>`.